# Change background-color of a color in CSS Grid Layout

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

I need some help for change the background color of a column in display: grid
I tried use background-image in .calendar, but the result is not good
How i change the background-color in specific column?

I put the code with SCSS in codepen
https://codepen.io/henrique-abdala/pen/JQpyeZ

i need something like this
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkbS4.png)

```css
.calendar {
  width: 100%;
}
.calendar .line {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-gap: 2px 10px;
}
.calendar .space {
  display: contents;
  background-color: #ddd;
  /* if display contents, this won't color */
}
.calendar .week-day, .calendar .day-label, .calendar .event {
  padding: 4px 10px;
}
.calendar .event {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.calendar .event-end {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.calendar .event-start {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.calendar [data-span-start="1"] {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
.calendar [data-span-start="2"] {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
.calendar [data-span-start="3"] {
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
.calendar [data-span-start="4"] {
  grid-column-start: 4;
}
.calendar [data-span-start="5"] {
  grid-column-start: 5;
}
.calendar [data-span-start="6"] {
  grid-column-start: 6;
}
.calendar [data-span-end="1"] {
  grid-column-end: span 1;
}
.calendar [data-span-end="2"] {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
.calendar [data-span-end="3"] {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
}
.calendar [data-span-end="4"] {
  grid-column-end: span 4;
}
.calendar [data-span-end="5"] {
  grid-column-end: span 5;
}
.calendar [data-span-end="6"] {
  grid-column-end: span 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="line-day">10H</div>
    <div class="line-day">11H10</div>
    <div class="line-day">15H</div>
    <div class="line-day">16H10</div>
    <div class="line-day">19H30</div>
    <div class="line-day">20H40</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="space">
      <h3  data-span-start="1" data-span-end="6">Sala 01</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="space">
      <div class="event event-start event-end" data-span-start="1" data-span-end="1">Moda</div>
    </div>
    <div class="space">
      <div class="event event-start event-end" data-span-start="2" data-span-end="1">Design</div>
    </div>
    <div class="space">
      <div class="event event-start event-end" data-span-start="3" data-span-end="1">Design</div>
    </div>
    <div class="space">
      <div class="event event-start event-end" data-span-start="4" data-span-end="1">Escultura</div>
    </div>
    <div class="space">
      <div class="event event-start event-end" data-span-start="5" data-span-end="1">Design</div>
    </div>
    <div class="space">
      <div class="event event-start event-end" data-span-start="6" data-span-end="1">Fotografia</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="space">
      <h3  data-span-start="1" data-span-end="6">Sala 02</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="space">
      <div class="event event-start event-end" data-span-start="1" data-span-end="2">Moda</div>
    </div>
    <div class="space">
      <div class="event event-start event-end" data-span-start="5" data-span-end="1">Design</div>
    </div>
    <div class="space">
      <div class="event event-start event-end" data-span-start="6" data-span-end="1">Fotografia</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="space">
      <h3  data-span-start="1" data-span-end="6">Sala 03</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="space">
      <div class="event event-start event-end" data-span-start="2" data-span-end="2">Moda</div>
    </div>
    <div class="space">
      <div class="event event-start event-end" data-span-start="4" data-span-end="1">Design</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why you need `display:contents`? simply remove the extra wrapper. I don't see the need of the `space` div

Comment: however I think a linear gradient should do: Please try this: `background:linear-gradient(90deg,#fff, #fff 16.66%, #abcdef 16.66%, #abcdef 33.33%, #fff 33.33%,#fff 50%, #abcdef 50%,#abcdef 66.66%, #fff 66.66%,#fff 83.33%, #abcdef 83.33%,#abcdef 100%);`

Comment: just move your data attributes to the .space container. make it simple ;) Even If you solve this, next question will be : how to make display:contents crossbrowser ...

Comment: @enxaneta works!!!! i didn't know this possible, thank you =)